# how Locked account runs services

Tags: command-line, systemd, session, accounts

I wonder how a locked account, typically `www-data`, can run a service, for example `apache2`, if it has `/usr/sbin/nologin` as shell?

Is there a way to do in a root session, something like this:

```
root# su serviceaccount -c "path-to-application parameters"
```

to "manually" execute the program behind the service with the same user that actually runs it, without getting

```
This account is currently not available.
```

due to `nologin`?

Answer (score 0):

Been thinking about this for a while. Got to some kind of conclusion

This service-accounts are not intended for interactive sessions, so they don't need a shell interpreter, they shouldn't have it indeed, for security reasons.

Systemd starts the processes of each service, and somehow assigns the corresponing user to each process.

Regarding the second question, the best way I found to test interactively the program run by a service, is simply, assiging a shell interpreter (/bin/bash tipically) to the user and the run the command:

```
  # su -u serviceaccount -c "executable parameters"
```

Off course it won't have exactly the same running env, but you could get it runnig and hopefully find the bug annoying you.

Don't forget to remove the shell interpreter from the account once you are done